# How to Bind Jquery Value to an HTML Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bind

How can i bind the url result from the jquery to the href ? as you can see on the html below. Thank you.

## JQUERY CODE

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#btnSearch").click(function(){
       var yearArray = []; 
      $("input:checkbox[name=Year]:checked").each(function(){
         yearArray.push($(this).val());
       });
       var makeArray = []; 
      $("input:checkbox[name=Make]:checked").each(function(){
         makeArray.push($(this).val());
       });
      var url="http://example.com/results?Year="+yearArray.join()+"&Model="+makeArray.join();
        alert(url);
   });
});

</script>
```

## HTML

```
<a href="/searchnew/{{ url }}"><button id="btnSearch" class="btn btn-cta margin-bottom-1x search-button cssBase"
                                        type="button""
                                        style="width: 262.5px;">Search</button></a>
```

Comment: jQuery doesn't works this way.

Comment: how can we implement that idea ? what is the solution the problem ?

Comment: Use id attribute for your a tag like this-

<a href="....." id="myLink" > ... </a>

And at the end of your jQuery code add the following:

var a = $('#myLink');
var href = a.attr('href');
a.attr('href', href + url);

Comment: The HTML is invalid, `a` element can't contain `button` element. You can select the link with a simple attribute selector: `link = $('[href*="{{ url }}"]');` which selects all the elements having a href attribute containing the text "{{ url }}". Notice, that until the button is clicked, the link will lead to a non-existing page.

Answer (score 0):

You can simpy add href attribute after creating link. What i mean by this is 
if your href tag is look like this

```
<a href="#" id="myurl">
$("#myurl").prop("href",url);
```

This will simply render your html like this

```
<a href="http://example.com/results?Year="......(your dynamic values here)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to add  tag on to button click. Instead, on click of button, within the function after you have prepared url, call

> location.href = "searchnew/" + url;

In case you have the base url for the app, you can prepend as well to have the complete url with you.

Answer (score 0):

Use id attribute for your a tag like this-

```
<a href="....." id="myLink" > ... </a>
```

And at the end of your jQuery code add the following:

```
var a = $('#myLink');
var href = a.attr('href');
a.attr('href', href + url);
```